# Working with two user interfaces - Qt 5.5

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a simple `MainWindow` which has a button and an `LineEdit`. When I type something and click a button, a new `Dialog` appears with a label that is supposed to display the string I typed.
So basically, I have trouble sending information to another UI.
I tried working with the new class with a string variable, but it didn't work.

I will try to give an example of what I want to do.

```
//ui2 Dialog
    ui2->label->setText(ui->LineEdit->text());
```

Comment: Fixed grammar and punctuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ui is a an private variable, so it's not accessible from another class.

```
//mainwindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*){
   this->_dialog = new Dialog(this);
   //...
}
MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
   _dialog->_labe->setText(ui->lineEdit->text());
}

//dialog.h
class Dialog{
public:
  QLabel* _label;
  Dialog(QWidget* ){
    _label = ui->label;
  }
}
```